# Laravel 4 htaccess redirect loop 2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

this is the .htaccess file now

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But i want to change this file as when request come from blog.domain.com it redirect to the /blog folder and other file to the index.php

Comment: So what did you use that caused the loop?

Comment: when i change url to /blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
#Redirecting blog.example.com to blog folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /blog/$1 [L,NC] 

#Redirect other requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: is it work when i put "/" it return me the public folder

Comment: What do you mean "when i put /" ?

Comment: Actually i also want to access the public folder as well.

Comment: i solved the problem but it's create a new one.when i put the url like this domain.com it redirect me to domin.com/public/.So how do i remove public

Comment: This may be because of your other rules or browsers cache, Clear your browser cache and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80740/discussion-between-moin-khan-and-starkeen).